# Tablix Expressions (Multiple Condition)

Tags: ssrs-2008

I'm currently experiencing
The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox137.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.

=(Variables!Seconds.Value <= 500,"PASS", "FAIL") OR (Variables!Seconds.Value < 0,"N/A","")

This is a results column. In event that seconds is negative number it will be N/A. which means anything less then 0.

any thoughts on my syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure where to begin with this as the syntax is almost entirely wrong, unfortunately.  From my best inference, I am guessing you want `N/A` if less than 0, `PASS` if less than or equal to 500, and `FAIL` for anything above that.  I'm also not sure why you're using variables rather than populating your data with a query and using the `Fields!...` syntax, but that's another issue entirely.  To fix your current issue, you've neglected to include the `IIF` function that you seem to be trying to use.  I think the expression you'll want is the following.

```
=IIF(Variables!Seconds.Value < 0, "N/A", IIF(Variables!Seconds.Value <= 500, "PASS", "FAIL"))
```

This will first check the variable to see if it is less than 0, printing `N/A` if so.  If false, it will evaluate the second `IIF` that will print `PASS` for less than 500 and `FAIL` for anything above 500.

Comment: After plugging this in, it worked without issue. I actually tried using Fields! approach and got errors.